# for loop to calculate mean by group (also ignore NA)

Tags: r, for-loop, group-by, na

I would like to create a `for loop`

1. to create a1, a2,...a10 as the variable of the group mean
2. to calculate the mean of variables b1, b2, b3....b10 based on a group variable `groupid`
3. to ignore NA when calculating mean, I used `na.rm=TRUE`

```
df <- within(df, {a1 = ave(as.numeric(as.character(b1)), groupid, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))})  
df <- within(df, {a2 = ave(as.numeric(as.character(b2)), groupid, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))})
.
.
.
df <- within(df, {a10 = ave(as.numeric(as.character(b10)), groupid, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))})
```

How can I rewrite these stupid 10 lines into an elegant `for loop`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the `groupid` is the same, we can do this with `mutate_at` to get the `mean` of all columns with the pattern `b\\d+`as column name and create new columns with 'a' as suffix

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(groupid) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(matches('^b\\d+$')), list(a = ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe can try the below

```
df <- sapply(1:10, function(k) eval(parse(text = sprintf("within(df, {a%d = ave(as.numeric(as.character(b%d)), groupid, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))})",k,k))))
```